# How to control SignalR from an API Endpoint

Tags: signalr, blazor, signalr-hub

I have a Blazor app that also has an API at the same time. I have an injected singleton that has some values. A page on my blazor app displays the same singleton's values. What my goal is to update the Blazore Page/Razor Component the clients are viewing when I update the singleton's value with the API.

I have been trying to use signalR similar to the Tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RQ_c3NPkgs

Below is my code:

## Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // All other services
    ...

    // Signal R
    app.AddSignalR();
}

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/_MessageHub");
});
```

## Blazor Page

```
@using Marel.LairageScanner.Services.Interfaces
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 
@using Marel.LairageScanner.BlazorApp.Data.Communication 
@inject IPenService penService

<b>Message Retrieved : @penService.CurrentPen</b><br>
<b>Connection State : @connectionState</b>

@code {      

    private HubConnection hubConnection;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("https://localhost:44332/_MessageHub")
        .Build();

        hubConnection.On(MessageCommand.Update, UpdateState);

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    void UpdateState() => StateHasChanged();
}
```

## API Endpoints

```
private readonly IPenService penService;
private readonly HubConnection hubConnection;

public ScannerController(penService)
{
    this.penService = penService;

    // Initalize thi hub controller
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:44332/_MessageHub")
    .Build();
}

[HttpPut("{value}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetValue(
    [FromRoute] string value,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    penService.CurrentPen = value;
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    await hubConnection.SendAsync(MessageCommand.Update);
    await hubConnection.StopAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

Hope this helps, if you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution, but uncertain why the other method didn't work.

Instead of using `SendAsync` I used `InvokeAsync` and passed down the method name. With `SendAsync` the Hub was not being hit. As mentioned I don't know why this is.